# who -t showing nothing in command prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, centos-6

In

> [root@localhost ~]# man who

-t means

> t, --time
>      print last system clock change

I changed the system time using using

> [root@localhost ~]# date -s 05:27:00
>
> Thu Jul 12 05:27:00 IST 2012

After that i checked the date, and its changed.

> [root@localhost ~]# date
>
> Thu Jul 12 05:27:02 IST 2012

but while running below command it's showing nothing why?

> [root@localhost ~]# who -t
>
> [root@localhost ~]#

I am using CentOS 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`who` does nothing more than read the *utmp* file `/run/utmp`<sup>1</sup>. Since the Linux kernel does not log clock changes by default, it remains up to the `date` program, or another utility, to add the necessary *utmp* entries. However, it doesn't seem that this was *ever* implemented in the GNU Coreutils version of `date`. (It is still done by `date` on [FreeBSD](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/bin/date/date.c?view=markup#l273), for example.)

(Keep in mind that *utmp* is, usually, reset every boot, so its "clock change" field is much less useful now than it was in the Unix mainframe days.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Other locations: `/var/run/utmp`, `/var/run/utx.active` (FreeBSD), `/var/adm/utmp`, `/etc/utmp`.